# How do I create a Tasker program that will open a browser URL only at certain time of the day?

Tags: tasker

I am anew to Tasker and the like. I have a passion for learning programming skills. Here I wanted to create a task where in the chrome browser would run at any point of time of day, however I would not be able to run any social networking websites at every point of time except certain hours. How do I go about creating such an app.

I am running Tasker from Moto G 2014.

Answer (score 0):

there are two ways of doing it:

---

### rooted phone

you'd need to edit `hosts` file located at `/system/etc`

in order to block access to chosen URL (let's choose google.com as an example), add following:

`127.0.0.1 google.com`

what will it do? redirect all `google.com` requests to localhost

after changing hosts file, restart your phone for the changes to take effect

### non-rooted phone

Although I have personally never used it, I suppose you could install an app called [Servers Ultimate](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.icecoldapps.serversultimate) which would run as a service on your phone, allowing you to turn predefined servers on/off (on the fly) using built-in tasker plugin.

You'd setup there your own DNS server and set a list of (dis)allowed IPs, so whenever you start that DNS, the rules would kick-in, restricting acces to chosen URLs

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is an old thread, but couldn't you create a time based profile to run every hour or at whatever point you choose?  All you would then need to do is create a task that uses the Net category, then the Browse URL category. Enter your URL and the page will open.